# Google image bug, transparent after clicking on an image

Tags: google-chrome, google-image-search, chromebug

I can't find anybody facing the same problem as mine.

Every time I click an image on google image, suddenly the whole page disappear, but I'm still able to click things just like everything is still there.
I already turn off all extension, use incognito mode, after finally I try to use inspect element, and found attribute stating "Opacity: 0" on the body. And after unchecking the box (Quick disable attribute in inspect element chrome) everything shows up again.
I'm so confused on why this is happening.

Does anyone have ever facing the same problem?
Or how do I fix it?
It's so frustrating, because I have to refresh the page, every time I click on an image, or switch between images

Answer (score 0):

so I was having this one. in the end, it was a virus.

In my case, it was showing an AD screen on the main google page, and in the `sources>gstatic.com` it had a different source which also was in a [unknown] source.

dug a bit up and discover some adware was using gstatic as a proxy to show ads on all browsers.

I solved it by running `malwarebytes`, it found it pretty quickly and solved it for me.

Posting this here because I'm hoping it helps people who search for this issue in the future.

[part of the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmZel.png)